# How to make a right or false detector in input() for math in python

Tags: python, math, input

I want to make a program that gives you an math problem and you need to answer it, if you answer it correctly i want it to print something and if you answer wrongly I want it to print something else

I have tried this

```
    my_boolean = True
import random

n1 = random.randint(1, 50)
n2 = random.randint(1, 50)
choice = random.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/'])
question = f"{n1} {choice} {n2}"

print(question)
if input() == True:
    print("Wow thats right")
else:
    print("That is not right!")
```

but when i answer something correctly it shows "That's not right!" if I remove the else nothing comes up even if you type it wrong or right.

Comment: `input() == True` checks if input is the boolean `True`. this never happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the correct answer depending on the operator +,- etc. chosen, then compare with the user's answer.

For this, you can make a variable `correct` for the correct answer.

```py
import random

n1 = random.randint(1, 50)
n2 = random.randint(1, 50)
choice = random.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/'])
question = f"{n1} {choice} {n2}"

print(question)

#now get the correct answer
if choice == '+': 
    correct = n1 + n2
elif choice == '*': 
    correct = n1 * n2
elif choice == '/': 
    correct = n1 / n2
elif choice == '-': 
    correct = n1 - n2
ans = int(input("Answer?"))
if ans == correct:
    print("Wow thats right")
else:
    print("That is not right!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Built-in `eval()` Function , it is very usefull :

```
import random

n1 = random.randint(1, 50)
n2 = random.randint(1, 50)

op = random.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/'])


question = f"{n1} {op} {n2} = ?"

result = eval(str(n1) + op + str(n2))
  
print(question)
user_answer = input("Please type your answer here: ")


if user_answer == str(result):
    print("Wow thats right")

else:
    print("That is not right!")
```